# print([dirty_dozen[0],[1]]) not understanding this line

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
fruits = ["Strawberries", "Nectarines", "Apples", "Grapes", "Peaches", "Cherries", "Pears"]
vegetables = ["Spinach", "Kale", "Tomatoes", "Celery", "Potatoes"]
 
dirty_dozen = [fruits, vegetables]
 
print(dirty_dozen[0][1])
```

i am not understanding
`print([dirty_dozen[0],[1]])` this line from code and what will be the output

Comment: Have you tried running the code? What part of it you do not understand?

Comment: 2 dimensional array, like in C

Comment: It's the same as `x=dirty_dozen[0]`, `y=x[1]`. What is `dirty_dozen[0]`? Could you see how you could use `...[1]` on that?

Comment: For a newbie, that is a legitimately confusing line. Note that you copied the line incorrectly in the text below your code, which may be adding to your confusion. Or were you asking about a different line of code?

Answer (score 4):

**These are 2 separate things**:

```
print(dirty_dozen) 

#[['Strawberries', 'Nectarines', 'Apples', 'Grapes', 'Peaches', 'Cherries', 'Pears'], ['Spinach', 'Kale', 'Tomatoes', 'Celery', 'Potatoes']]
```

First element of `dirty_dozen` and a list `[1]`

```
print([dirty_dozen[0],[1]])
#[['Strawberries', 'Nectarines', 'Apples', 'Grapes', 'Peaches', 'Cherries', 'Pears'], [1]]
```

Second element of First element of `dirty_dozen`

```
print(dirty_dozen[0][1])
#Nectarines
```

You need to understand the difference between them:

`[dirty_dozen[0],[1]]` and `dirty_dozen[0][1]`

Answer (score 2):

```
dirty_dozen = [fruits, vegetables]
print(dirty_dozen[0][1])
```

In the first line above you create a new list called `dirty_dozen`, which contains two entries. Entry[0] is a list of fruits, and entry[1] is a list of vegetables.
So in the second line, you are printing entry[1] of dirty_dozen[0], which is the second entry in the fruits list. As running the code would make clear.

Answer (score 2):

`fruits` is a list. `vegetables` is another list.

Lists in Python have indexes to represent each item inside the list. And the first index is always `0`.

`dirty_dozen` is a third list, comprised of the first item (index `0`) as the `fruit` list, and the second item (index `1`) as the `vegetables` list.

When you want to request `dirty_dozen` for the value of `[0][1]` you are saying "show me the value of the item with index=1 (Nectarines) inside the item of index=0 (Fruits) in memory."

Answer (score 1):

Fruits is a list consisting of the fruits seen between the [] symbols.
Vegetables is also a list, consisting of the vegetables between the [] symbols.
'dirty_dozen' is a third list, that consists of the lists 'fruits' and 'vegetables'.
So if you write dirty_dozen[0][1], that will take the 0. element of dirty_dozen (which is the list 'vegetables') and then return the 1. element of that list (which is 'Nectarines').

Comment: Fruits is not an array - it's a list

Answer (score 0):

It will return you "Nectarines" because with

```
dirty_dozen = [fruits, vegetables]
```

you have created a two dimensional list.

by giving 0 as first number in parameter you navigate to the firstly mentioned fruits.
by giving 1 as second number in parameter you navigate to the second element of that list which is "Nectarines"